# Knockout js foreach binding alphabetically

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm totally new in knockout.

Good you help me to understand how I need to change this code:

> ```
> <ol class="items" data-bind="foreach: getDisplayedItems()">
>     <li class="item">
>         <a class="simple" data-bind="html: label, attr: {href:url}, visible: count >= 1, css: { active: is_selected }"></a>
>         <span class="count" data-bind="text: count"></span>
>     </li>
> </ol>
> ```

to make it in alphabetically order?

Thanks for any tips
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort them in-place:

```html
<ol class="items" data-bind="foreach: getDisplayedItems().sort((a, b) => ko.unwrap(a.label) < ko.unwrap(b.label) ? -1 : 1)">
    <li class="item">
        <a class="simple" data-bind="html: label, attr: {href:url}, visible: count >= 1, css: { active: is_selected }"></a>
        <span class="count" data-bind="text: count"></span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

but I think that's ugly, and it's not re-usable. It's better to make a new observable array that contains the items in the right order:

```
function App {
    // the observable you already have
    this.getDisplayedItems = ko.observableArray([...]);

    // a computed observable based on that
    this.getDisplayedItemsAlphabetical = ko.pureComputed(() => this.getDisplayedItems.sorted((a, b) => ko.unwrap(a.label) < ko.unwrap(b.label) ? -1 : 1));
}
```

and

```html
<ol class="items" data-bind="foreach: getDisplayedItemsAlphabetical">
```

Comment: Small note: your `getDisplayedItemsAlphabetical` pure computed has a side effect of sorting the array in `getDisplayedItems` in place (even though it won't trigger a value mutation there).

Comment: @user3297291 That's a very good point, I had not thought of that. Fixed!

Comment: @Dnc44 Is `getDisplayedItems` a regular function or an observable in your viewmodel?

Comment: @Tomalak is a function